# Sum column depending on values from another column on a single row (Pivot columns)

Tags: sql, database, time-series, questdb

I have a table with this schema

```
CREATE TABLE 'trades' (
  symbol SYMBOL capacity 256 CACHE,
  side SYMBOL capacity 256 CACHE,
  price DOUBLE,
  amount DOUBLE,
  timestamp TIMESTAMP
) timestamp (timestamp) PARTITION BY DAY WAL DEDUP UPSERT KEYS(symbol, timestamp);
```

And I have some data like this (the real data is at sub-second resolution, but for the example this should suffice)

```
INSERT INTO trades (symbol, side, price, amount, timestamp) VALUES
('BTC-USD', 'buy', 25757.235813, 0.020919, '2023-09-05T16:00:00.000000Z'),
('BTC-USD', 'sell', 25776.646252, 0.069064, '2023-09-05T16:15:00.000000Z'),
('BTC-USD', 'sell', 25791.132914, 0.048749, '2023-09-05T16:30:00.000000Z'),
('BTC-USD', 'buy', 25760.595216, 0.024248, '2023-09-05T16:45:00.000000Z');
```

I know I can get the total amount for the sells and the buys per day by doing this:

```
SELECT 
    timestamp, symbol, side, sum(amount) as sell    
FROM trades
SAMPLE by 1d;
```

But this gives me two rows, one for the 'sell' side and one for the 'buy' side. Any ideas to show this in a single row?

[image: Results show two rows with the totals for each side, symbol, and day]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to pivot the rows into columns by using conditional statements. In QuestDB we can use the `Case` keyword for this, as in

```
SELECT 
    timestamp, symbol, 
    sum(case when side = 'sell' then amount else 0 end) as sell,
    sum(case when side = 'buy' then amount else 0 end) as buy
FROM trades
SAMPLE by 1d;
```

This will sum all the values from rows with side equal 'sell' in a column we name `sell` and the same with all the rows with value 'buy'.

[image: A row with a column sell and a column buy with the right amounts]